# fuzzy match 2 DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy

There is a package called fuzzy_pandas that can use levenshtein for ratio string matching. With some great examples [here](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzy-pandas/)

As this exemple :

```
import pandas as pd
import fuzzy_pandas as fpd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Strawberry']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['Aple', 'Mango', 'Orag', 'Straw', 'Bannanna', 'Berry']})

results = fpd.fuzzy_merge(df1, df2,
            left_on='Key',
            right_on='Key',
            method='levenshtein',
            threshold=0.6)

results.head()
```

So, I don’t know if it’s possible to display the threshold value in the results.

The output is:

```
Key Key
0   Apple   Aple
1   Banana  Bannanna
2   Orange  Orag
```

And I want something like:

```
Key Key Ratio
0   Apple   Aple 0.81
1   Banana  Bannanna 0.87
2   Orange  Orag 0.78

Maybe with another library
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Thank you I update the Question

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778079/how-to-replace-string-in-python-from-a-list-of-possible-strings/55778634#55778634)

Comment: Thank you, so with fuzzy_pandas it's not possible. But I do it with DiffLib.

Answer (score 0):

To create a threshold values, you can do the following code:

results['Similarity']= results.apply(lambda x:fuzz.token_set_ratio(x['Key'],x['Key']),axis=1)